quarkus automatic opentelemetry span creation for smallrye applications
Quarkus provides a quickstart project for opentelemety integration showing how you can automatically create a span of kind Client or Server inside an http application.
In the same way, can quarkus opentelemetry extension automatically create a span of kind Consumer or Producer in a Quarkus SmallRye Reactive Messaging application without adding any code?
I would welcome any kind of quickstart or tuto that can help, showing manual stuff to do if needed.
Thanks a lot

Quarkus does indeed instrument messaging interactions done with Quarkus Messaging.
Here are the relevant excerpts from the Javadoc:
ReactiveMessagingTracingIncomingDecorator:
/**
 * Intercepts incoming messages from Reactive Messaging connectors.
 * <p>
 * For incoming messages, it fetches OpenTelemetry context from the message and attaches to the duplicated context of the
 * message.
 * Consumer methods will be called on this duplicated context, so the OpenTelemetry context associated with the incoming message
 * will be propagated.
 */

ReactiveMessagingTracingOutgoingDecorator:
/**
 * Intercepts outgoing messages from Reactive Messaging connectors.
 * <p>
 * For outgoing messages, if the message doesn't already contain a tracing metadata, it attaches one with the current
 * OpenTelemetry context.
 * Reactive messaging outbound connectors, if tracing is supported, will use that context as parent span to trace outbound
 * message transmission.
 */

